# Determining RSS refresh rates

Tags: xml, rss, http-headers

**Do all RSS feeds support [HTTP ETags](http://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/http-etag.html)/last-modified headers for indicating whether the feed has been updated?**

For feeds which do not include last-modified headers, what is the best way of determining how often the feed updates?

I'm hoping to tailor the number of requests I send to each feed based on its update frequency to cut down on bandwidth (following ~2k feeds...)

Comment: For that matter, what criteria do RSS readers typically use for determining how often to refresh feeds to ensure that no posts are lost?

Answer (score 2):

No, not all feeds support ETag/If-Modified headers (and unfortunately that does not tell you when to fetch a resource, just that it has not been updated).

There is no general way of determining when a feed has been updated. However, among the most popular methods is the [PubSubHubbub](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/PubSubHubbub) protocol, which was designed for that. (It actually goes further and sends you the new content in the feed so you don't even have to fetch it).
The problem is that it's not supported by *all* feeds out there (up to 30% depending on the types of feeds you're dealing with: blogs, news sites, ecommerce... etc).

Another solution is to check http://superfeedr.Com (disclaimer: I created that beast:p) because we'll do all the dirty work for you and you can just sit and wait for us to send you the data (using open protocols).

Comment: Merci bien. I had a feeling that only some would support the more efficient protocols... Superfeedr is a great product, but with a limited budget and an increasingly large number of feeds to parse, I figured I'd try rolling my own setup. I'm therefore interested in the dirty work ;)

Comment: If the problem is just price: let's chat :) julien@superfeedr.com We can help!

Comment: Tell you what, I might just do that. But now I've got an intellectual itch to scratch, so I'm going to at least give a custom solution a shot. Thanks for the offer, I'll keep you posted :)

Answer (score 2):

To find new items compare the items of the retrieved feed with those found earlier. If the items have a GUID use that for the comparison, otherwise you could combine fields like link + title, or keep a MD5 hash of the complete item.

Use this knowledge to adapt the polling interval, like I described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6651638/4167).

Comment: I really like the idea of dynamic polling frequency using +/- 10% increments. How did you find such a system worked for you?

Comment: This mechanism ran in a personal aggregator on my PC, and worked well. The system retrieved around 3000 items per day and stayed current with the sources. I used a higher percentage to decrease the frequency, so when new content was found the waiting period dropped quickly to adapt to sources that restarted publishing faster. The problem for me was coming up with a way to discover interesting stuff.